# Unable to autowire bean in Spring integration test

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-test

I am trying to `autowire` a `bean` for unit testing purpose.
I'm working with `annotation` based configuration classes and not using `xml` based `application-context`.

**Porblem:** It says `Failed to load ApplicationContext`

Here is my code.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppContextLoader.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class StockTest
{
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StockTest.class);
    @Autowired
    private StockGenerator generator;

    @Test
    public void someTest()
    {//some code here}
    }
}
```

And my configuration class looks like this

```
@Configuration
public class AppContextLoader
{
    @Bean
    public StockGenerator stockProvider()
    {
        StockGenerator stock = new StockGenerator();
        return stock;
    }
}
```

**Note:** `StockGenerator` is spring managed so I am not sure how to handle it here. I am following [this](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) example.

Or is there any other way to autowire beans when one is not using `xml` based approach.

Comment: Your test class is also StockTest and you are autowiring StockTest in it?

Comment: Can you add your stacktrace as well. After Failed to load ApplicationContext.

Comment: @CodeItLikeAmeen, sorry it was a typo, updated my question.

Comment: Please add the error stack trace in the question so that we know can debug why ApplicationContext fails to load.

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing what the cause of the problem is. So as already requested, please provide the entire stack trace for the error you are encountering.